# Qt QTableView 1 line vertical size

Tags: qt

I have the following to add a QTableView to a QWidget:

```
QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
QTableView *tableView = new QTableView;
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
tableView->verticalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
tableView->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
vLayout->addWidget(tableView);
```

This widget will use model which load data from MySQL... And there is only one line of content, so I would like to make the view just height enough to show one line. How to approach this issue?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#sizeHint

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that this works best:

```
    const auto height = table.horizontalHeader()->sizeHint().height() + table.rowHeight(0);
    table.setMinimumHeight(height);
    table.setMaximumHeight(height);
```

You force the table to keep the exact size specified by you: the header size + the size of a single row.